# What technique should I use for hand wrappings?

Tags: punching, fist, protective-equipment

There are so many techniques to be found on the internet. At the Uni (where I train kickboxing), they just refer to the internet.

I keep on winding up with crappy hand wrappings. The one that stays on my hand well, doesn't feel like it's really protecting the knuckles.

Comment: It sounds like you are not wrapping them tight enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link shows how I was taught to wrap my hands:
https://www.mmafightgearonline.com/Articles.asp?ID=131

To prevent link rot here are the steps from it:

> **Step 1**
>
> Your hand should be held open in a relaxed position, with your fingers
>   spread apart. Begin by placing the hand wrap thumb loop around your
>   thumb and be sure that the 'This Side Down' text on the hand wrap is
>   against your skin. Bring the wrap across the back of your hand and
>   wrap around your wrist 2 or 3 times.
>
> Be sure to wrap high enough (2" to 3" up from your wrist joint) on the
>   wrist to maximize support. You want to keep the hand wrap snug
>   throughout this process, but not so tight that it will cut off your
>   circulation.
>
> **Step 2**
>
> From the wrist, bring the wrap across the back of your hand and around
>   your palm, then across the top of your knuckles.
>
> **Step 3**
>
> Wrap around the knuckle area 2 to 3 times. From the top of your
>   knuckles, wrap across the back of your hand toward your wrist and
>   around. This will create an 'x' pattern across the back of the hand.
>
> Repeat the 'x' pattern 2 or 3 times.
>
> **Step 4**
>
> Continue around the palm of your hand to the base of your thumb. Wrap
>   completely around your thumb and back toward your wrist on the palm
>   side of your hand.
>
> It is important to keep the wrap from twisting while wrapping the
>   thumb.
>
> **Step 5**
>
> Continue wrapping around the back of your hand to the thumb and once
>   again wrap around your thumb, this time from the opposite direction.
>
> **Step 6**
>
> Wrap from the thumb over the back of your hand and around your wrist.
>
> **Step 7**
>
> Continue around your wrist, over the back of your hand and through the
>   space between your pinky and ring fingers. Wrap around your palm back
>   toward your wrist and repeat the steps for each finger.
>
> Be sure to keep the wrap as flat as possible and twist free.
>
> **Step 8**
>
> With the last finger completed, bring the wrap across the palm back
>   toward your wrist.
>
> **Step 9**
>
> Continue wrapping across the back of your hand toward your knuckles.
>
> **Step 10**
>
> Wrap once more around the top of the knuckles and across the back of
>   your hand toward your wrist.
>
> **Step 11**
>
> Secure your wrist with the remaining hand wrap. Be sure to wrap it
>   snugly to provide support for your wrist.
>
> **Step 12**
>
> Fasten the Hook & Loop closure and you're done. (IE:velcro)
>
> If your having trouble with it sliding off, it's likely that it's to
>   loose, of you've finished your wrap in a less then ideal position.

Comment: I made some small changes to it so that it looks a little bit the same after step 8, but thanks!

Comment: >Seems to me that the https://www.mmafightgearonline.com/Articles.asp?ID=131 link is dead at this time.

Comment: aw man, that sucks.  it had some good pictures.  good thing we pasted the rules in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the wraps are coming off, then maybe you are wrapping the knuckles too much?  Maybe using too many horizontal loops without crossing low to high?  That tends to unravel easily.

Everybody's hands are different, but I tend to focus more on wrapping the wrist and thumb, which are both vulnerable if you are hitting a heavy bag.

A good tight fist is the best way to support the knuckles, so make sure you don't wrap so tight that you can't make a solid fist.

Comment: I agree that the wrist are the most vulnerable. My knuckles are hardened enough due training on concrete (I know it doesn't sound nice). I actually want to protect my wrist because we train a lot with gloves on gloves and sometimes they just hit your wrist instead of your hand. Do you have a vid of the technique you use?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different ways, and eventually just came up with my own way.  All I do is rotate between wrapping the wrist, wrapping the thumb, and doing an x on the hand.  Adjust this pattern so that you finish with 1 or 2 final wraps on the wrist.  Pause to make a tight fist every few wraps to make sure you aren't cutting circulation.  People with long, thin fingers probably would want more knuckle protection than this, but it suits me just fine.